# Почему через сессию hibernet юзер из базы возвращается как объект, а через JpaRepository как прокси объект

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

В моем приложении в слое контроллер я могу получить юзера 2 способами через JpaRepository(метод getOne) и через сессию hibernet(метод getUserByKey)
Слой контроллер:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("desk")
public class MainController {

    final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public MainController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable long id) {
       // User user = userService.getOne(id);      //через JpaRepository
          User user = userService.getUserByKey(id);  //через сессию hibernet
        return user;
    }
}
```

В базе данных у меня храниться юзер с двумя машинами(связь один ко многим)
Слой модель:
Таблица User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@ToString(of = {"id", "test"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
public class User {
    public User() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    private String address;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Car.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "car", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ownerId", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Car> childIds;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public List<Car> getChildIds() {
        return childIds;
    }

    public void setChildIds(List<Car> childIds) {
        this.childIds = childIds;
    }
}
```

Таблица Car:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
@ToString(of = {"id", "test"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
public class Car {
    public Car() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private long ownerId;

    private String model;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "user", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Long> parentIds;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getOwnerId() {
        return ownerId;
    }

    public void setOwnerId(long ownerId) {
        this.ownerId = ownerId;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public List<Long> getParentIds() {
        return parentIds;
    }

    public void setParentIds(List<Long> parentIds) {
        this.parentIds = parentIds;
    }
}
```

Сервисный слой:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImple implements UserService {

    final UserRepo userRepo;
    final DAO userDAO;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImple(UserRepo userRepo, DAO userDAO) {
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    public User getOne(long id) {
        return userRepo.getOne(id); //через JpaRepository
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserByKey(long id) {
        return userDAO.getUserFromBd(id); //через сессию hibernet
    }
}
```

Репозиторий JPA:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

Слой DAO:

```
@Repository
public class DAO implements GenericDao<User> {

    private SessionFactory hibernateFactory;

    @Autowired
    public DAO(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
        if (factory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class) == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("factory is not a hibernate factory");
        }
        this.hibernateFactory = factory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserFromBd(long user_id) {

        Object query = hibernateFactory.openSession().createQuery("FROM User WHERE id =:user_id")
                .setParameter("user_id", user_id)
                .uniqueResult();
        return (User) query;
    }
}
```

Вопросы:

1) Почему когда я использую сессию hibernet(метод getUserByKey) для получения юзера, в дебаге в контроллере я вижу объект, даже если fetch = FetchType.LAZY на всех моделях?

2) Почему когда я использую JpaRepository(метод getOne) для получения юзера, в дебаге в контроллере я вижу прокси объект, даже если fetch = FetchType.EAGER на всех моделях?

3) Как получить объект используя JpaRepository?

Answer (score 1):

Если прочесть API документацию по [JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.8.RELEASE/api/index.html?overview-summary.html), то в ней написано, что метод `getOne()` возвращает **ссылку** на сущность:

> Returns a **reference** to the entity with the given identifier.

То есть внутри этого метода используется `EntityManager.getReference()` вместо `EntityManager.find()` или аналог в Hibernate API `Session.load()`. Для того, чтобы получиться саму сущность, а не **ссылку**, необходимо обратиться к данным сущности, например `user.getName()`, в **текущей транзакции** (иначе загрузить сущность уже не получиться).

Для чего это нужно? У Вас есть сущность `User`, в которой храниться список `Car`-ов. Добавить юзеру новую машину (допустим с `id = 1234`) можно 2-мя способами:

---

```
Car car = entityManager.find(Car.class, 1234L);
user.getChildIds().add(car);
```

---

```
Car car = entityManager.getReference(Car.class, 1234L);
user.getChildIds().add(car);
```

Второй способ будет быстрее, поскольку сущность `car` будет загружена **без данных**.

Comment: Возможно ли получить прокси объект используя сессию hibernet?

Comment: @harly `session.load()` возвращает прокси (если сущности с таким идентификатором уже нету в `Persistence Context-е`)